# Back button with webview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I'm trying to implement back button with webview in my screen but not really sure why it's looking like this so I'll be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(

        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, bottom: 20),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                      iconsPath + "arrow-left.svg",
                      color:  Color(0xFF282828),
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 20),

                ],
                
              ),
              
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: WebView(initialUrl: "https://google.com", javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted
            )
            )],
         
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

get `Container` height & width value.

change your code to this.

```
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 200,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl: "https://google.com",
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              ),
            ),
```